# Pascal I need to modify the program as the result to be write in text file maxim.out

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have a program which is counting the biggest number from 3 numbers. I need to modify the program as the result to be write in text file maxim.out  (PASCAL)

Comment: It would be best to show us what you have written so far and show us (e.g. in a comment) where you want to write to file. Also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can write the value (assuming it is an integer and it has the name, say, `yourValue`) with:

```
var
  maximFile: Text;

...

  Assign(maximFile, 'maxim.out'); // link the name to the Text variable
  Rewrite(maximFile);             // open it for writing
  Writeln(maximFile, yourValue);  // write the value as a line of its own
  Close(maximFile);               // close the file
```

You can then read back the value later on with:

```
  Assign(maximFile, 'maxim.out');
  Reset(maximFile);
  Readln(maximFile, yourValue);
  Close(maximFile);
```

I did not add any error handling (e.g. if the file can't be found, or if it is readonly, or empty, or ...). Depending on settings, that is either done with exceptions or with `IOResult` values. Read the documentation on how to do that. There should be examples in the docs.

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvote. The question is about how to save a value to a file called maxim.out. ISTM that this is a valid answer.

Comment: Probably there is someone around who doesn't understand. I made 1 up. I chose to reply with little information because the question had little information too. I preferred to keep the same behavior - more helpful... ;-)

Comment: @linuxfan: One of the upvotes on your answer is from me...  :-)

Comment: I did imagine it.

Answer (score -1):

You should read about "file management in pascal". Anyway, declare a variable of type textfile:

```
var
  outputfile    : TextFile;
```

then assignfile() to it your name of choice (maxim.out), rewrite() the file, use writeln() to write into it, and finally closefile() it.

You can find a complete example program here: http://wiki.freepascal.org/File_Handling_In_Pascal

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question

Comment: @tofro I don't understand, but you can explain to me what's wrong.

Comment: @tofro: I can't see why you can't see it. This answers the question, although a little more code would have been nice.